# How do I implement a bit adder?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

I want to design a circuit in logism that takes as input a 16-bit signal, and then counts the number of set bits and outputs a 4-bit signal that is the sum of those set bits.

Example:

[image: input] input ----> output [image: output]

Comment: why do you want to design this? ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to compare the number of set bits in 2 16-bit inputs. I already have that part done with a magnitude comparator and this is something I am having trouble with designing efficiently.

Comment: Note that you'll need 5 bits to represent the full range of possible results: 0 to 16.

Comment: `way too inefficient` Please state a cost model to judge efficiency. (Basically, *fast bit counting* **is** expensive.) What exactly is a *component*, and just how did you *chain adders*?

Comment: (@DaveTweed: 123Questions image does show 5 bits in *ao*. Maybe your comment should go to [ElectronicsStudent](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/668772/274544) (EEPROM approach).)

Comment: @123Questions Are you permitted to use sequential logic? Or does it have to be combinatorial? (I'm thinking of 'inefficient' in the sense of the number of logic gates.) Also, please show what you tried that created too much logic. It will help a lot to see what you tried and what you consider to be "too much."

Comment: @123Q To me, the obvious implementation of a simple bit counter in combinatorial logic would be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkDH3.png). It took only about 4 minutes to draw that out. And it works. So is that what you meant by "too much?" 26 HA's and 11 2-in OR gates?

Comment: This is actually what I was trying to implement. My previous version used multiple-bit adders and my understanding is not at the point of accomplishing this.

Comment: @123Q Are you writing to me or someone else? In any case, [here's a better documented form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9reUy.png). To add 16 bits together you need 7 FA and 1 HA. That produces 8 carry-outs and the lowest order sum bit. To add 8 bits at the next higher significance, you need 3 FA and 1 HA. That produces 4 carry-outs and the next higher order sum bit. To add 4 bits at this next higher significance, you need 1 FA and 1 HA. That produces 2 carry-outs and the next higher order sum bit. And to add the last 2 carry-outs you just need 1 HA. Should be easier to see now. Not complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As your question does not state a clear application like:

- Discrete Logic
- HDL
- Software (C e.g.)

i am covering all three:

**(1) Software**

```
uint8_t countSetBits(uint32_t n)
{
    uint8_t count = 0;
 
    for (uint8_t i = 0U; i < 32U; i++)
    {
        count += (n & 0x1U);    // check last bit
        n >>= 1U;
    }
 
    return count;
}
```

This returns the number of '1' bits in a `32` bit Field by looping over the field `n` and shifting the contents. Everytime a bit is set, a counter `count` is incremented.

**(2) VHDL**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity num_ones_for is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           ones : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0));
end num_ones_for;

architecture Behavioral of num_ones_for is
begin
process(A)
variable count : unsigned(5 downto 0) := "000000";
begin
    count := "000000";   --initialize count variable.
    for i in 0 to 31 loop   --for all the bits.
        count := count + ("000000" & A(i));   --Add the bit to the count.
    end loop;
    ones <= std_logic_vector(count);    --assign the count to output.
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

This code "loops" (Caution: HDL does not loop, as it creates a parallel implementation!) through the vector and increments the counter field everytime, a bit is set.

**(3) Discrete Logic**

For a implemenation in discrete logic, there are two basic options:

- Parallel
- Sequential

These two paradigms represent the `Parallel=HDL` and `Sequential=C` approaches.

You need to choose which approach to take based on the following parameters:

- Board space available
- Number of ICs possible (Cost etc.)
- Speed requirements
- Power requirements

I will go with the sequential approach here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPmkPD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works as follows: The Intput Word is presented via a 16Bit parallel bus. When the Latch-Signal is asserted, the counter is Reset to 0 and the Data is latched into the Parallel-To-Serial Register. When the Clock is applied, the Counter increments if the Count-Enable is set ( This signal comes from the Serial-Shift Register and represents the data-field to count the bits in). After 16 Clocks have been applied, the number of Bits set is presented in Binary on the 4-Bit output.

**(4) A Little Trick**

You can also use a 16-Bit EEProm for this.

Basically, you programm the memory with the number of bits set in the address at every address. So somewhat like

Adr = 000 : 0

Adr = 001 : 1

Adr = 010 : 1

Adr = 011 : 2

Adr = 100 : 1

And so on....

You then use it like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftm6Cn.png)</sup>

On the output, you can use the lower 4-Bits only!

This gives you a synchronus single cycle "Bits-set-in-Field-Counter".

Comment: (16 *address* bit \*ROM, and either generating "the 16 output bit" with a 16 input AND, or use 5 bits - 65536×5 minimum. (Same problem with counter.))